# Proving that an orthonormal system close to a basis is also a basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq\mathcal{H}$ be an orthonormal basis and $f_n$ be an orthonormal system such that 
$(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq\mathcal{H}$ and $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\|e_n-f_n\|^2 <1.$$ Prove that $f_n$ is also a basis.

I am kind of stuck and can't figure out how to prove that $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a basis.
I tried to prove by contradiction that if $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not  a basis then $\exists   x \neq0 \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $\langle x,f_n \rangle=0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I also know that $\|e_n-f_n\|^2 \to 0 \implies Re(\langle e_n,f_n \rangle) \to 1$

I then tried to write $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \langle x,e_n \rangle e_n$ from which I get that

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \overline{ \langle x,e_k \rangle} \langle e_k,f_n \rangle \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

But I do not know how to proceed. Any hints would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathcal{H}$ with $\lVert x\rVert = 1$. Show that $x$ cannot be in the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{span} \{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Since $\{ e_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a Hilbert basis of $\mathcal{H}$, we can write

$$x = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_n\cdot e_n.$$

Consider now

$$y = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_n \cdot f_n.$$

Then we have

$$\lVert x-y\rVert^2 \leqslant \Biggl(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \lvert c_n\rvert\cdot \lVert e_n - f_n\rVert\Biggr)^2 \leqslant \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \lvert c_n\rvert^2\cdot \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \lVert e_n - f_n\rVert^2 < 1.$$

It follows that

$$\left\lVert x - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \langle x,f_n\rangle f_n\right\rVert^2 \leqslant \lVert x-y\rVert^2 < 1 = \lVert x\rVert^2,$$

so some $\langle x, f_n\rangle$ must be nonzero.

---

In fact, we have something much stronger: It already follows that $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is also an orthonormal basis when

$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \lVert e_n - f_n\rVert^2 < +\infty.\tag{1}$$

**Proof:** Choose $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. By $(1)$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\sum_{n \geqslant N} \lVert e_n - f_n\rVert^2 < \varepsilon^2.$$

Let $E = \overline{\operatorname{span} \{ e_n : n \geqslant N\}}$ and $F = \overline{\operatorname{span} \{ f_n : n \geqslant N\}}$. Define

\begin{gather}
A \colon E^{\perp} \to F^{\perp},\quad x \mapsto x - P_F x,\\
B \colon F^{\perp} \to E^{\perp},\quad x \mapsto x - P_E x,
\end{gather}

where $P_E,\,P_F$ are the orthogonal projections to $E$ resp. $F$.

By $(1)$, we have

$$\lVert P_F x\rVert^2 = \Biggl\lVert \sum_{n \geqslant N} \langle x,f_n\rangle f_n\Biggr\rVert^2 = \sum_{n\geqslant N} \lvert \langle x, f_n\rangle\rvert^2 = \sum_{n\geqslant N} \lvert \langle x, f_n - e_n\rangle\rvert^2 \leqslant \lVert x\rVert^2\sum_{n\geqslant N} \lVert f_n - e_n\rVert^2 < \varepsilon^2\lVert x\rVert^2$$

for all $x \in E^{\perp}$, and similarly

$$\lVert P_E x\rVert^2 = \sum_{n \geqslant N} \lvert\langle x, e_n\rangle\rvert^2 = \sum_{n\geqslant N} \lvert\langle x, e_n - f_n\rangle\rvert^2 < \varepsilon^2\lVert x\rVert^2$$

for all $x\in F^{\perp}$.

For $x \in E^{\perp}$ we have

\begin{align}
BA x &= B(x - P_F x) = (x - P_F x) - P_E(x - P_F x)\\
&= x - P_F x + P_E P_F x = x - (I - P_E)P_F x\\
&= x - P_{E^{\perp}} P_F x
\end{align}

since $P_E x = 0$, and hence $\lVert (I_{E^{\perp}} - BA) x\rVert = \lVert P_{E^{\perp}} P_F x\rVert \leqslant \lVert P_F x\rVert < \varepsilon \lVert x\rVert$. It follows that $BA$ is an automorphism of $E^{\perp}$, in particular that $A$ is injective, and hence $\dim E^{\perp} \leqslant \dim F^{\perp}$.

In the same way, for $x \in F^{\perp}$ we have

\begin{align}
AB x &= A(x - P_E x) = (x - P_E x) - P_F(x - P_E x)\\
&= x - P_E x + P_F P_E x = x - (I - P_F)P_E x\\
&= x - P_{F^{\perp}} P_E x,
\end{align}

and consequently $\lVert I_{F^{\perp}} - AB\rVert < \varepsilon$. So $AB$ is an automorphism of $F^{\perp}$, in particular $B$ is injective and hence $\dim F^{\perp} \leqslant \dim E^{\perp}$.

Since $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is by assumption a Hilbert basis of $\mathcal{H}$, it follows that $(e_n)_{n < N}$ is a basis of $E^{\perp}$, whence $\dim E^{\perp} = N$ (we assume $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, the dimension would be $N-1$ otherwise). By the orthonormality of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, the $N$-element family $(f_n)_{n < N}$ is linearly independent and contained in $F^{\perp}$. Since $\dim F^{\perp} = N$, it is a basis of $F^{\perp}$, and thus $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is total in $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: I somehow didnt see the solution. Now that I read it I don't understand your argument. I see why the whole  x cannot be in the orthogonal complement of the span of $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ but how does that imply that $x$ is in the span of  $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. I mean if that were true wouldn't the following be true?
$$\left\lVert x - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \langle x,f_n\rangle f_n\right\rVert^2 = 0$$

Comment: If the closure of $\operatorname{span} \{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ were not all of $\mathcal{H}$, then there would be an $x_0 \in (\operatorname{span} \{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\})^\perp$ with $\lVert x_0\rVert = 1$. Then we would have $$\Biggl\lVert x_0 - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \langle x_0,f_n\rangle f_n\Biggr\rVert^2 = \lVert x_0\rVert^2 = 1.$$ But we have shown that $$\Biggl\lVert x - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \langle x,f_n\rangle f_n\Biggr\rVert^2 < 1$$ for **every** $x\in \mathcal{H}$ with $\lVert x\rVert = 1$.

Comment: Ah Thank you. I should have thought of that !! :(

Comment: what if it is finite instead of less than 1 in the problem

Comment: @89085731 Thanks, that was an interesting question. I didn't know whether it would suffice to merely require finiteness of the sum at the beginning. Turns out it does, see the updated answer.

Comment: In the first part of your answer, why $$\left\lVert x - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \langle x,f_n\rangle f_n\right\rVert^2 \leqslant \lVert x-y\rVert^2 $$?

Comment: This seems incorrect. If we take $(e_n)$ to be the standard basis of $\ell^2$ and $(f_n) = (0, e_2, e_3, e_4, \ldots)$, then the sum of the squared distances is finite, but $(f_n)$ is not an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the mapping $T: H \to H, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n e_n \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n f_n$.

Then we have, for $x \in H$:

$$
\| x - T x \|^2 = \left\| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n (e_n - x_n) \right\|^2 \overset{\text{Hölder}}{\leq} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\lambda_n|^2 \right) \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \| e_n - x_n \|^2 \right) = \| x \|^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \| e_n - x_n \|^2
$$

Therefore, $\|\operatorname{id} - T \| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \| e_n - x_n \|^2} < 1$, so by the Neumann series, $T$ is invertible, hence surjective, and hence $\operatorname{span}\{f_n\}$ is dense in $H$.